# Adding clock points to d3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm very new to D3 - in fact I only started yesterday - have a donut pie chart here:

```
var dataset = new Array();

dataset[0] = {"value":"50","color":"red"};
dataset[1] = {"value":"20","color":"blue"};

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d){return d.value;});

    var h = w = 500;
    var center = w / 2;
    var outerRadius = ((h/2)-5);
    var innerRadius = outerRadius-10;
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var arcOutter = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(outerRadius)
        .outerRadius(outerRadius + 1);

    var arcInner = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .outerRadius(innerRadius - 1);


    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    //Set up groups
    var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + center + ", " + center + ")");


    //Set up outter arc groups
    var outterArcs = svg.selectAll("g.outter-arc")
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "outter-arc")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + center + ", " + center + ")");

    //Set up outter arc groups
    var innerArcs = svg.selectAll("g.inner-arc")
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "inner-arc")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + center + ", " + center + ")");


    //Draw arc paths
    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) 
        {
        return d.data.color;
    }).attr("d", arc);

    //Draw outter arc paths
    outterArcs.append("path")
        .attr("fill", 'green')
        .attr("d", arcOutter).style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('stroke-width', 0);

    //Draw inner arc paths
    innerArcs.append("path")
        .attr("fill", 'green')
        .attr("d", arcInner).style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('stroke-width', 0);
```

[jsFiddle chart](http://jsfiddle.net/uowe8vhb/)

But I'm struggling to add 4 clock points and their time tables to it, (12am, 3pm, 6pm, 9pm), I've tried searching clock examples but they're all working clocks, not just the points.

I want it to look pretty much like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how aestheticaly correct it is, but here it goes. What you could do, is add 4 line segments in your chart at these locations:

> [w/2, 0],[w/2,h],[0,h/2],[w,h/2]

You can achieve that if you add the following lines:

```
   var x=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,outerRadius]).range([0,w])
   var y=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,outerRadius]).range([h,0])

   svg.append('line').attr("x1",x(outerRadius/2)).attr("y1",0).attr("x2",x(outerRadius/2)).attr("y2",20)
   svg.append('line').attr("x1",x(outerRadius/2)).attr("y1",y(outerRadius)).attr("x2",x(outerRadius/2)).attr("y2",y(outerRadius)-20)

   svg.append('line').attr("x1",0).attr("y1",y(outerRadius/2)).attr("x2",20).attr("y2",y(outerRadius/2))
   svg.append('line').attr("x1",x(outerRadius)).attr("y1",y(outerRadius/2)).attr("x2",x(outerRadius)-20).attr("y2",y(outerRadius/2))
```

Please note that you have to create a css entry, so that the line is shown:

```
line{   
    display:block;
    stroke:black;
}
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c9jorqje/1)

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad to help. Can you accept the answer so that the question closes? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the lovely example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/6475678).

```
var radians = 0.0174532925;
var hourScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0,330])
    .domain([0,11]);

var labelGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform','translate(' + (center + margin) + ',' + (center + margin) + ')');

labelGroup.selectAll('.hour-label')
    .data([12,3,6,9])
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'hour-label')
        .attr('text-anchor','middle')
        .style('font-size','16pt')
        .attr('x',function(d){                
            return outerRadius * Math.sin(hourScale(d)*radians);
        })
        .attr('y',function(d){
            return -outerRadius * Math.cos(hourScale(d)*radians);
        })
        .text(function(d){
            return d;
        });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uowe8vhb/3/).